Python проверка на пустоту XML
Помогите пожалуйста как избавиться от ошибки:

ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes or attributes. Be sure to
specify in xpath the parent nodes of children and attributes to
parse. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to
define namespaces and use them in xpath.

Не могу понять как проверить файл на пустоту как в пример моего XML и кода  ниже.
Приходит пустой XML, из-за него я получаю ошибку.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <table/>

Код:
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 


def READ_XML():
        DATA_TODAY = datetime.datetime.now() #определяем текущую дату и время
        file_path = r'C:\xxx\xxx2\1' #директория с файлом
        NAME_FILE = os.listdir(file_path)[0]# получение названия файла в директроии
        file_path2 = r'C:\xxx\xxx2\1\{}'.format(NAME_FILE)
        
        
      
        
        
        
        try:
            tree = ET.parse(file_path2)        
            XML_ERROR = 'OK'
            print(XML_ERROR)
            XML_FILE = pd.read_xml(file_path2) # чтение хмл
        except ET.ParseError:
            XML_ERROR = 'BAD'
            print(XML_ERROR)
        


попробуйте в except не определять исключение, не указывайте его. Насколько я вижу вы ловите  ParseError, а прилетает ValueError. Или добавьте еще один except-блок с ValueError

Просто проверяйте на наличие элементов в XML перед попыткой его парсинга.
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import datetime

def READ_XML():
    DATA_TODAY = datetime.datetime.now() # определяем текущую дату и время
    file_path = r'C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\xml' # директория с файлом
    NAME_FILE = os.listdir(file_path)[0] # получение названия файла в директории
    print(NAME_FILE)
    file_path2 = r'C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\xml\{}'.format(NAME_FILE)
    
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(file_path2)
        root = tree.getroot()
        
        if len(root) == 0 and not root.attrib: 
            XML_ERROR = 'BAD TREE'
            print(XML_ERROR)
        else:
            XML_ERROR = 'OK'
            print(XML_ERROR)
            XML_FILE = pd.read_xml(file_path2) 
    except ET.ParseError:
        XML_ERROR = 'PARSE BAD'
        print(XML_ERROR)

READ_XML()

